# Does searching for a remote post URL on Mastodon rely on the origin server?

Tags: cached-webpages, mastodon

On Mastodon, you can load a post from another server by searching for the original post [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

Once loaded, that post is saved on your own server.  It will be kept even if the other server fails.

Question: If the other server fails, so the URL no longer works in the web browser, can you still find your servers copy by searching for the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: if the origin server is dead, you cannot search for their posts using the original URL.

Tested on mastodonapp.uk, Mastodon v4.2.7.

Steps:

1. find a dead mastodon server
2. search for the domain name
3. click on one of the users
4. click on one of the posts
5. from the "..." menu, "open original page".
6. copy the URL of the dead post into the search box

Result: "Could not find anything for these search terms".